# SONAR SOURCE (SonarLint & SonarQube)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have heard about the sonar source that manage source code quality. I have VS-2015. I have installed Sonar extension in VS (SonarLint) but not to know how to use that. I mean i add the extension in VS which is enabled. My local site is hosted in IIS server so that i don't need to Build + compile and run it on VS. also tell me that is it necessary to use SonarQube with SonarLint ?. if yes than why?

Comment: It is possible to use SonarLint in VS without SonarQube: see [the product page](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html) for an example what to expect. But to get all the benifits you should link SonarLint to a SonarQube instance. Have a look at the [SonarQube home page](https://www.sonarqube.org/).

Comment: To get an idea of what you can do with SonarLint, it's a good idea to look around the [SonarLint website](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/). You could skip parts that don't interesting to you. The information is not very well structured for now, but it will be improved over the coming months.